# Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class cv::Mat __thiscall ft_data::get_image(int,int)"

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am creating an face recognition program using but i have some kind of error and i don't have and idea how to solve it ...

```
Mat im = data.get_image(i,0); if(im.empty())continue; //Unresolved external symbol
vector<Point2f> p = data.get_points(i,false); int n = p.size(); //Unresolved external symbol
```

this are the errors i get

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class cv::Mat __thiscall ft_data::get_image(int,int)" (?get_image@ft_data@@QAE?AVMat@cv@@HH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall face_detector::train(class ft_data &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class cv::Mat const &,bool,bool,float,float,int,class cv::Size_<int>)" (?train@face_detector@@QAEXAAVft_data@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABVMat@cv@@_N3MMHV?$Size_@H@6@@Z)    D:\Workshop\Final\C++ Console Application\AAM-Raw\AAM-Raw\AAM-Raw.obj   AAM-Raw
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::vector<class cv::Point_<float>,class std::allocator<class cv::Point_<float> > > __thiscall ft_data::get_points(int,bool)" (?get_points@ft_data@@QAE?AV?$vector@V?$Point_@M@cv@@V?$allocator@V?$Point_@M@cv@@@std@@@std@@H_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall face_detector::train(class ft_data &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class cv::Mat const &,bool,bool,float,float,int,class cv::Size_<int>)" (?train@face_detector@@QAEXAAVft_data@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABVMat@cv@@_N3MMHV?$Size_@H@6@@Z) D:\Workshop\Final\C++ Console Application\AAM-Raw\AAM-Raw\AAM-Raw.obj   AAM-Raw
```

it doesn't show error before i put `#include <GL/glext.h>`, i need that header to declare a variabel

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and c++ console application

Comment: This quick Google search might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sorry but i still don't get it after read it, can you give me an example?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be any of these problems. Please look harder to find related problem and proceed to solve it. I don't have your full code, that's why I cannot tell which one is the problem.

I guess your problem occurs because of the `train` function in your source code. I prefer you to look for the below problems in that piece of code. Must likely, you have the global constant problem, but missing function body or variable is also possible.

**Global Constants**:

> C++ global constants have static linkage. This is different than C. If
>   you try to use a global constant in C++ in multiple files you get an
>   unresolved external error. The compiler optimizes global constants
>   out, leaving no space reserved for the variable. One way to resolve
>   this error is to include the const initializations in a header file
>   and include that header in your CPP files when necessary, just as if
>   it was function prototype. Another possibility is to make the variable
>   non-constant and use a constant reference when assessing it.

**Missing Function Body or Variable**

> With just a function prototype, the compiler can continue without
>   error, but the linker cannot resolve a call to an address because
>   there is no function code or variable space reserved. You will not see
>   this error until you create a call to the function that the linker
>   must resolve.

**Automatic (Function Scope) Variables**

> A variable declared within a function can only be used within the
>   scope of that function.

**Function Inlining Problems**

> If you are using function inlining, you must:
>
> - Have the inline functions implemented in the header file you include.
> - Have inlining turned ON in the header file.
>
> If you are using the #pragma inline_depth compiler directive, make
>   sure you have a value of 2 or greater set. A value of zero will turn
>   off inlining. Also make sure you are using the /Ob1 or /Ob2 compiler
>   options. Mixing inline and non-inline compile options on different
>   modules can sometimes cause problems. If a C++ library is created with
>   function inlining turned on (/Ob1 or /Ob2) but the corresponding
>   header file describing the functions has inlining turned off (no
>   option), you will get error LNK2001. The functions do not get inlined
>   into the code from the header file, but since they are not in the
>   library file there is no address to resolve the reference. Similarly,
>   a project that uses function inlining yet defines the functions in a
>   .cpp file rather than in the header file will also get LNK2019. The
>   header file is included everywhere deemed appropriate, but the
>   functions are only inlined when the .cpp file passes through the
>   compiler; therefore, the linker sees the functions as unresolved
>   externals when used in other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to switch video studio project to 64 bit if you are using a 64 bit version of OpenCV libraries, or compiled OpenCV using a 64 bit configuration.

Visual Studio will give Unresolved External errors when trying to use 64 bit libraries in a 32bit project, which is really confusing, because you would have the correct libraries included.. at least by name.